# Is there a longer than int Java List?

Tags: java, arraylist, long-integer, maxlength

I can't seem to find a Java `List` that's max length is `long`'s max value.

Does such a `List` exist?

If so, where?

Comment: Do you really need to hold that amount of data in memory?

Comment: Are you expecting to hold more than 2 billion elements in a list? Given that Object headers are 8 bytes, plus 4 bytes per reference, you're looking at (8 bytes+4 bytes)*2 billion = 24GB of memory, at the very lowest end of a "full" int-length list. And it's likely worse for a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @Reimeus List is just an interface, implementation might not hold all the data in memory.

Comment: Consider using a LinkedList

Comment: Hmm. Just one reference is required - File, for example.

Comment: @sigpwned Yes, over the long run, this application should be expected to manage those magnitudes quickly, and implementing a better solution later would not be easy.

Comment: @Basilevs Thank you Basilevs!  Does that comment mean that the entire `List` does not need to be stored in memory?

Comment: @Gracchus There is no standard implementation which doesn't store its data in memory. However custom implementation of List interface is perfectly capable to store its data in external storage.

Comment: Lists are abused frequently where a more streaming approached should be used like an iterator or writer. Try to make your library / app use these interfaces instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @afsantos says, the `ArrayList` class is inherently limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries because of the limitations of Java arrays.

`LinkedList` doesn't have this limitation, but it is (nonetheless) expensive:

- Each entry incurs an memory overhead of 2 references plus the size of an object header ... compared to just one reference for an array-based representation.
- Indexing is an `O(N)` operation compared with `O(1)` for an array-based list.

Here is a link to Java library that supports *huge* in-memory collections using direct mapped memory and/or encoding of the elements:

- http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

And here is a link to a *huge* collections library with an ArrayList analog that uses 2-level arrays (arrays of arrays) to avoid the 32 bit address limit.

- https://github.com/eobermuhlner/jhuge

There could be other alternatives out there.

One could also envisage a "big" variant of regular array lists that used an array of arrays rather than a single array.  But if you allow insertion into the middle of the list, it becomes difficult / expensive to achieve `O(1)` lookup.  (That might be why I couldn't find an example with Google ...)

Answer (score 6):

From the `List` documentation:

> `int size()`
>
> Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

So, even if a specific implementation of `List` holds `Long.MAX_VALUE` elements, you wouldn't know, using the standard `List` interface.

I'm not sure if one exists, but my bet would be on `LinkedList`, since `ArrayList` is based on arrays, and those can't hold more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.

Comment: Thank you afsantos!  Yes, `LinkedList` seems to limited only by memory.

Answer (score 4):

As `List.get(int)` accepts int as its argument, it is impossible to address entries with indexes greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Do note, however, that `Iterable<?>` or `Map<Long, ?>` can address much more data. As List implements Iterable it could contain any amount of data (that part being not exposed with int-based List's API).