# Super-Massive Collections

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections

My question is, are there any implementations of a list or map in Java that provide near-to O(1) getting and adding time, but **are not constrained by the max array size**. ArrayList and HashMap fit the first condition, and fail the second, but LinkedList fails the first condition and fits the second. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your collections constrained by the available memory?  As soon as you start writing to disk, you lose the O(1) performance.

Comment: If I didn't make some stupid mistake such a collection would require more than 16 GB of memory (assuming 8-byte object references). Are they really that big?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc What does disk vs. memory have to do with asymptotic runtime?

Comment: @JamesWierzba If you don't have enough memory, the Big-Oh doesn't matter that much anymore. It would be nice to hear his use case. A single JVM solution sounds suspicious when people are asking about over 2 billion objects in a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few third-party libraries which make this possible, although I'm not sure of the exact big-O performance of them:

- [HugeCollections](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vanilla-java/wikis/HugeCollections.wiki) (mentioned in [an answer to a question about bigger-than-int lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371964/1391325))
- [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) (mentioned in [an answer to yet another question about bigger-than-int lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025979/1391325))

These questions should really be merged...

Comment: @Meguy26: Can you please accept this answer if it helped you?-- I'm currently dredging for some extra reputation points. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh! My apologies. I will accept. The exact problem I was dealing with had a different solution, but you certainly answered the question I asked!